# Format cells to reference another sheet based on row number

Tags: excel, formula

I am working in a workbook with 200+ sheets, and one of the sheets is a summary page that must reference some totals values from the other sheets. To do this, I have a column with formulas such as =+'130'!D57. In this instance, the cell is referencing cell D57 on the sheet named '130'. The next cell down would be =+'131'!D57, and so on for 200+ rows. I have been struggling to find a way to apply this formatting to all rows in the column. Usually I would do this by highlighting a few cells and dragging down from the bottom right corner, but this just creates exact copies of the highlighted cells rather than incrementing the sheet counts. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction here.

Comment: One pointer would be the INDIRECT formula.

Comment: So I've been trying to do something like =+INDIRECT(B141&"!D57"), where B141 holds the name of the sheet I am referencing. I am just getting the #REF error though. Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: That should work. What exactly is in B141?

Comment: B141 is a cell containing the name of the sheet I am trying to reference. In this case, it is just '131' as I am trying to reference cell D57 of sheet named '131'

Comment: That's correct. The sheet name is not recognised. Check for trailing or leading spaces. Is there only one workbook open?

Comment: There are no trailing spaces in the cell or sheet name. No other workbooks are open either. I tried changing the contents of B141 and the name of the other sheet to "test", still getting the same #REF result. It still works when entering the sheet name manually as follows: =+test!D57

Comment: Very strange. Can you post a screenshot of your set up?

Comment: Here is an idea of what I am working with https://imgur.com/JiJk90U

Comment: That's not the formula you quoted above.

Comment: Here it is with the other formula https://imgur.com/Ye5iH5T

Comment: I don't understand why you're not using the formula you used in your first comment. It's hardly surprising it's not been working as you've been using the wrong formula!

Comment: Now elaborated in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the INDIRECT formula.

If the cell B141 contains the name of a sheet, then

```
=INDIRECT(B141 & "!D57")
```

will return the value of cell D57 in that cell.

So you can copy that formula down and it will update if you have other sheet names in B142 etc.

It's safer to use

```
=INDIRECT("'" & B141 & "'!D57")
```

in case your sheet names have spaces in them.

Comment: This worked for me. Not sure why I used the wrong equation in the screenshot, think I was trying to follow too many different tutorials at once. Thanks